# MailChimp API: Ruby code results in just printing the word "Array" on new campaign

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, methods, rake, mailchimp

I am using the `gibbon` gem to utilize the MailChimp API to create new campaigns for my Rails 3.2 app. Currently I am in the process of building a rake task that finds all `Job` records with a state of `posted` and sends information about them to MailChimp in a new campaign that will be edited by hand by a team member each morning with news/announcements and sent out to subscribers. I'm having trouble getting my Ruby code to correctly print out the information about the jobs that is being sent as part of the campaign.

```
# mailchimp.rake

posted_jobs = Job.posted

def print_jobs(jobs)
    jobs.each do |j|
        if j.when == "ASAP"
            datetime = "ASAP"
        else
            datetime = Chronic.parse(j.when_datetime).strftime("%B %d at %I:%M%p")
        end
        "#{datetime}: #{j.category.name.capitalize} in #{j.where_city}" 
    end 
end
...
# hash for new Campaign
...
...
:content=>
  {
   :sections=>{:body_content01 => print_jobs(posted_jobs)}
  }
```

This results in just printing the word "Array" in the e-mail like so:

[image: Array]

What it really should be is a simple list of the base information about the job. I understand what is happening (last thing being evaluated is the entire array of ActiveRecord objects) but don't know how to fix it in this case since I'm in a rake task. Thank you for any help/advice!

**EDIT**

What I would really like to be able to do is render a partial in the `sections` line. From some searching I have seen a lot of suggestions for rendering a partial in a rake task but they all seem rather complicated and version-specific. If anyone knows of a good walkthrough of this that definitely works with Rails 3.2, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I think what I really need is to render a partial here

Answer (score 0):

The method returns the last thing which in this case is an array.
Try making it

```
def print_jobs(jobs)
    jobs.map do |j|
        if j.when == "ASAP"
            datetime = "ASAP"
        else
            datetime = Chronic.parse(j.when_datetime).strftime("%B %d at %I:%M%p")
        end
        "#{datetime}: #{j.category.name.capitalize} in #{j.where_city}" 
    end.join("\n")
end
```

Which should map the jobs into an array and then join them into a string, with a newline for each

Comment: That seems to have printed out the IDs of each Job, like so: 
#2 #3 #4 #5 #6 #22